# Remove Magento Elevate Zoom

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom, elevate

I want to remove magento default jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js zoom ectension on the product view page.

i tried removing the commenting js file from catalog.xml file but not working.

Please help me
Thanks  In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
```

Comment below code

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
        });
    //]]>
    </script>-->
```

Comment: i am using rwd theme media.phtml and i didnt found the above script

Comment: Have you commented your js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js file in your catalog.xml file?

Comment: yes.then i am getting prototype elevate zoom ja errors

Comment: open skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js and comment line no. 649 i.e. image.elevateZoom(); clear your magento cache.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove elevatezoom by inserting the following in my local.xml:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: The problem is, is that the console will show an error when you remove this file, coming from the app.js file: Uncaught TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function. Anyway to clean that up in a good practice?